# FFMPEG - How to demux LIVE multi-program transport stream?

Tags: ffmpeg

Assume that I have a fifo of bytes that is essentially coming from a capture card.  Basically, this is NOT A FILE ON DISK.

The data in this fifo is a *multi-program* MPEG-TS.  There are three programs, each containing a video stream and one or more audio streams.

When I run FFmpeg by piping in the fifo, it displays the programs and the streams inside of it.  However, sometimes Program 1 contains streams 0:1 and 0:3 and other times it may contain 0:4 and 0:2.  Even though the PID's always stay the same, FFmpeg tends to give them a random numbering.

My question:  Is there a way to select the appropriate streams - I'm fine with selecting by PID - using FFmpeg?  (I'm using CLI, btw)

Keep in mind that the *map* option in FFmpeg will *not* work because the stream numbers are "randomized" each time I run the ffmpeg command.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this question.  The title and first paragraph strongly emphasize that the data is streamed to ffmpeg, but for the rest of the question it isn't clear why this is relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say you are capturing using v4l2 from /dev/video0, then you can map using the program id like this:

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -map 0:p:keep_pid -map -0:p:first_remove_pid -map -0:p:second_remove_pid output.m2ts
```

Checkout: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-specifiers-1 and http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options

Comment: If a TS contain multiple programs (TV programs that captured by DVB-T), how can split it? For example I have a TS file that contain football + cooking + cartoon .How can i split this TS file to 3 mpg files?

Comment: @Mr.Hyde I've added an example of that here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map

Comment: @rogerdpack No no, I means All TV shows are in one TS. I think the only way to split them from each other is using EPG.

Comment: @Mr.Hyde Are they in separate programs/program id's? Even if they're not, they probably have different pids (the "0x406" from that example 8) so you could map them in that way.

Comment: @rogerdpack How to attach related EPG to demuxed program?

Comment: @Mr.Hyde I don't think its possibly (though with a "-c copy" it might be) since FFmpeg doesn't even read EPG today.

Comment: @Mr.Hyde If you have a question then please actually [Ask](http://superuser.com/questions/ask) it.  Do not simply spam every related question or answer with comments.

Comment: @Mr.Hyde Specifically the comment section on every ffmpeg question should not be considered your own personal support group. Comments are intended to clarify the answer itself or clear up a point from the question, you should not be asking new questions in comments on old answers.  You should instead be using the [Ask Question](http://superuser.com/questions/ask) button.